# C# hook or inject any browser

Tags: c#, javascript, browser, hook, code-injection

I am writing a c# WPF Application and wanted to know if it would be possible to create a hook on any browser like Chrome, Safari, FF or even Opera. What I want to do is to manually reload the active Tab or inject a JavaScript like live.js which does quite the same (if I understood live.js correctly).

The only thing don't want the user to do is to install an extra extension for his browser.

I have also thought about if it's possible to change the resources the browser process loaded to the local memory or something but I had no clue how to do so at all.

Comment: What is the relation between your WPF app and the browser?

Comment: That's the problem: there is none. Both are in different processes and I want to inject my files to any browser process running or to None if the user has no browser Running at all.

Comment: did you find any solution ??